# Unable to authenticate to schemaregistry with base auth and TLS certificate

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc, confluent-schema-registry

I am want to read from a kafka topic hosted on on-prem cluster and write to gcp bucket. Schema registry requires both basic auth and TLS authentication.
I tried below but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
object KafkaConnection {
  val brokers = broker1:port,...
  val security = "SASL_SSL"

  val schemaRegistryUrl = "**https**:abc.ca"
}
//deserializer code
class KafkaDeserializer{

val props = Map(
  "basic.auth.credentials.source" -> "USER_INFO",
  "schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info" -> "username:password",
  "schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location" -> "./truststore.jks",
  "schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password" -> "pwd"
).asJava

  var schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 100, props) // with Serializable
  val kafkaAvroDeserializer = new AvroDeserializer(schemaRegistryClient)  with Serializable


  class AvroDeserializer extends AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer {
    def this(client: SchemaRegistryClient) {
      this()
      this.schemaRegistry = client
    }

    override def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = {
      val genericRecord = super.deserialize(bytes).asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]
      genericRecord.toString
    }
  }
  object DeserializerWrapper {
    val deserializer = kafkaAvroDeserializer
  }

}
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

spark.udf.register("deserialize", (bytes: Array[Byte]) =>
  Deserializer.DeserializerWrapper.deserializer.deserialize(bytes)
)

  val kafkaDataFrame = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", security)
    .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka")
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "./truststore.jks")
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", "pwd")
    .option("subscribe", topic)
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
    .option("kafka.group.id", "consumer_group_name")
    .load()

val valueDataFrame = kafkaDataFrame.selectExpr("""deserialize(value) AS message""", "key", "topic", "partition", "offset", "timestamp", "timestampType")
```

I passed base authentication credentials and truststore certificate as above but I am getting below **error** . I am not sure if this is due to https connection or the incorrect trust store reference as the msg says Trust anchor for certification path not found.

````
ryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:880)
        at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:751)
        at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:716)
        at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:833)
        at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:706)
        at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:230)
        at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:209)
        at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.waitForHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:547)
        at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.getOutputStream(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:290)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:465)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:203)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1572)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1500)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:185)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:229)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getVersion(RestService.java:423)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getVersion(RestService.java:415)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaMetadata(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:201)
        at Logger.AvroConsumer$.main(AvroConsumer.scala:24)
        at Logger.AvroConsumer.main(AvroConsumer.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:732)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.```
````

Comment: That wrapper class may not be the best option. Check out https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I dont see any support for https or anyway to configure tls cert details for schema registry.

Comment: Does it explicitly say there is no HTTPS / TLS support? Any schema registry client configuration property is [passed directly through to the internal client library](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/blob/master/src/main/scala/za/co/absa/abris/avro/registry/ConfluentRegistryClient.scala#L31) without modification.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I tried passing the configuration property to client library but I got the same error. I tried using AbrisConfig but dont know how to import this.